# Android GridView making items fit on every screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm using gridvew as layout to fill my items, circle buttons, but i'm having problems fitting a big grid, 11 x 11.  When I use bigger screen it fits but it stops half way?  Is this because of the szie I put in my roundbutton.xml? On my phone smaller screen it does fit and extends to the end to the end of the screen.  I need to fit the screen, whatever size for a 11 x 11?

gridview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="11"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</GridView>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="O"
android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
android:layout_column="1" 
android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
```

roundedbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
        <size 
       android:width="5dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

activity_main.java

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.button_item, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
```

adapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that you have to count `device width and height runtime`

```
int width = devicewidth/11 ;
int height =deviceheight/11 ;
```

using this parameter you have to pass in `GridView's Adapter`

```
android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams parms = new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(width , height);
```

for resize its cell.

Comment: Where would this go? In main activity or in adapter? See above additional code.

Comment: How do you get devicewidth and deviceheight? Not really following your suggestion, do you have a source or if possible give a example? Thanks.  I assume you mean runtime in the onCreate in the main activity and make those values public and static so they can be shared with the adapter?

Comment: Able to figure out getting the dimensions but I don't pass parms anywhere to gridview. How would I got about that?

Comment: @MAXGEN http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2014/03/gridview-making-items-fit-on-every.html

Comment: Does your main layout have gridview?  Also you have two activities and one of them called adapter, not sure why you have two them named the same though? Theres only slight difference of function to disableview? Will I have problem with a custom adapter and buttons as items instead of images? Would you suggest not using onClick adapter inside of the adapter and instead use it like your doing, with the main activity? Thanks.

Comment: Okay I check your source code in the RAR you attached, I was able to figure some things out.  The only problem is that on either small 5 inch Nexus 5 screen and a bigger Nexus 7 screen, ROW 11 (ROW 10 index from zero) will not fit on either screen? Before the problem was on a smaller screen, the rows would scroll off the screen but have a scroll bar which isn't good either. I need all 11 on screen without scroll bar on both sizes of screen?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just decrease the result of column_height. I was able to get the last row on.  Not sure why, the resulting calculation is off by a row?

Comment: may be you have to calculate proper with height.

Comment: @ParagChauhan great answer! The src code you provided on GitHub was definitely helpful! However, I experienced (with your code) some white space in the corners for certain dimension sizes like 12X12 (http://imgur.com/jYIdc67)... Is there any way to center the GridView? Because, I even tried padding it, but it would just stack up on the previous white corners. Thanks!

Comment: @ParagChauhan can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944627/gridview-and-its-images-is-not-fit-for-all-screensize

Answer (score 0):

To adjusting Gridview to screen size

In `onCreate` take rowHeight :

//Get root view

```
root = binding.root
```

// Or you can use `findviewbyid(R.id.root)`

```
view.onGlobalLayout {
            rowHeight =
                root.measuredHeight / currentPageNumberOfRow
            fillView(appsList)
        }
```

In adapter:

```
          override fun getView(position: Int, ConvertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
            var mConvertView = ConvertView
            if (layoutInflater == null) {
                layoutInflater =
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as 
                        layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.item_app_shortcut, null)
          }

           if (mConvertView == null) {
                mConvertView =
                layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.item_child_launcher_app, null)
               
        //Add this: 

         mConvertView.layoutParams = AbsListView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, rowHeight)

            }
```

Dont forget set row Button:

```
     android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

To fit on screen